# Elementos Creados en el Dom (nodo) no funcionan al dar un click

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodejs, express

muy buenos dias a todos , tengo un elemento div en mi estructura HTML5 que es la siguiente

```
<div class="app-sidebar__overlay" data-toggle="sidebar"></div>
        <aside class="app-sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-img">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index-2.html"><img alt="..." class="navbar-brand-img main-logo" src="assets/img/brand/logo-dark.png"> <img alt="..." class="navbar-brand-img logo" src="assets/img/brand/logo.png"></a>
                <ul class="side-menu">
                    <li class="slide">
                        <a class="side-menu__item active" data-toggle="slide" href="#"><i class="side-menu__icon fe fe-home"></i><span class="side-menu__label">Dashboard</span><i class="angle fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                        <ul class="slide-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a class="slide-item" href="index-2.html">Retail Sales Dashboard</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="slide-item" href="dashboard-social.html">Social Dashboard</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="slide-item" href="dashboard-marketing.html">Marketing Dashboard</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="slide-item" href="dashboard-it.html">IT Dashboard</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="slide-item" href="dashboard-cryptocurrency.html">Cryptocurrency Dashboard</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <div id="nav-menu">

                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </aside>
        <!-- Sidebar menu-->
```

en mi div con la referencia de id "nav-menu" lleno elementos que serian los menus y submenus pero estos elemntos vienen de mi base de datos, adjunto mi Javascript :

```
    let dashboard = {
    menu: [],
    submenu : []
};
let menu = '';
$(document).ready(function(){

    getDataMenu();
    setTimeout(function(){
        for(let i in dashboard.menu){

            menu += `
                <li class="">
                <a class="side-menu__item active" data-toggle="slide" href="#"><i class="side-menu__icon ${dashboard.menu[i]['icono']}"></i><span class="side-menu__label">${dashboard.menu[i]['nombre']}</span><i class="angle fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                <ul class="slide-menu">
                `

            menu += retornarLi(dashboard.menu[i]['idmodulo']); 

            menu +=`</ul></li>`


        }

        $("#nav-menu").append(menu)
        $("#nav-menu > li").addClass("slide");
        /*
        $("#nav-menu li").on("click", function(){

        })
        */


    },100)



})


function retornarLi(idmodulo){
    let li = ``;
    for(let e in dashboard.submenu){
        if(dashboard.submenu[e]['idmodulo'] == idmodulo){
            li += `

                    <li>
                        <a class="slide-item" href="${dashboard.submenu[e]['ruta']}">${dashboard.submenu[e]['nombre']}</a>
                    </li>

                    `
        }
    }
    return li;
}

function getDataMenu(){
    // =======================MENU=====================================
    fetch(`${window.ruta}/menus`,{
        method:"GET",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
    })
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then( res => {
        let data = res.modulos;

        for(i in data){
            dashboard.menu.push({
                'idmodulo': data[i]['idmodulo'],
                'nombre': data[i]['nombre'],
                'icono' : data[i]['icono']
            })
        }

    }).catch(error => console.log(error))

    //================================SUB MENU==============================
    fetch(`${window.ruta}/submenu`,{
        method:"GET",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        let datos = res.submodulos

        for(e in datos){
            dashboard.submenu.push({
                'idmodulo': datos[e]['idmodulo'],
                'nombre': datos[e]['nombre'],
                'ruta': datos[e]['ruta']
            })
        }

    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

en mi javascript hago la consulta a mi api donde me trae mis menu's y submenu's
pero al darle .html lo agrega todo normal pero al darle un click no se desplazan
adjunto una imagen con una prueba de la primer elemento que esta en html en duro tal y como deberia funcionar los demas al dar click (dashboard y usuarios no funcionan) el primer dashboard es codigo html que esta en el nav
[image: imagen dashboard]

en que puedo estar fallando ? Muchas Gracias de Antemano

Comment: Lo que sucede es que para que  los elementos del menú se muevan se les aplica alguna función de js. Los menús que estás agregando no se mueven porque la función js que los activa se ejecutó antes de que ellos estuvieran ahí. Para solucionarlo debes volver a ejecutar el código js que activa los menús.

Comment: osea darles denuevo la ruta del script? <script src="path/to/here"></script>??

Comment: No, en los js de la plantilla por lo general hay un custom.js que contiene el código que inicializa todos los componentes js, incluyendo los menús. Si encuentras ese archivo podrías envolver todo su contenido en una función, y cuando agregues los nuevos elementos del menú invocas esa función para que active todos los elementos nuevos. Son sugerencias que te hago en base a mi experiencia pero no puedo ser certero sin saber como está estructurada la plantilla. Puedes publicar la sección donde se cargan todos los  archivos js.

Comment: No veo en tu código cómo le quieres añadir el comportamiento que dices que falta, no hay ningún *event listener* para los clicks.

Comment: @PabloLozano por eso mismo los estoy creando con la misma clase.

Answer (score 1):

Yo utilizo `$(document).on()` para cuando quiero ejecutar código en elementos creados posteriormente a la creación del evento
Ejemplo:

```
$(document).on("click",".test_elem",function(){
   //Código aquí
});
```

Esto utiliza **jquery** para funcionar